# Codeigniter 4 pagination only shows page number 1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, pagination, codeigniter-4

Codeigniter 4 pagination links only shows page number 1 but when i manually change the page number in the URL, the other results page results are displayed but still only page 1 link is showing.

Below is my code so far

```
// BaseController.php
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function initController(){
        $this->pager = \Config\Services::pager();
    }
}
```

```
// BlogsController.php
class BlogsController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $this->data['meta_title'] = 'Blogs Listing';

        $this->model = new BlogModel();

        $this->data['blogs'] = $this->model->orderBy('created_at, id', 'DESC')->paginate(2);
        $this->data['pager'] = $this->pager;

        return view('blogs/index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

```
// inside the view
<?php echo $pager->links(); ?>

// for debugging, in view
// returns 1 as total page count instead of 3
<?php echo $pager->getPageCount(); ?>
```

i have only 5 records in the database. expecting 3 pages with 2 record per page and with first, last or the next and previous links to show, but only page 1 link is showing.

**Edit**
this is the code for the model class

```
// BaseModel is the model from this CodeIgniter 4 Relations library
// https://github.com/hlohrenz/CI4-Relationship-Query-Builder
class BlogModel extends BaseModel {
    // model related properties and methods
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$this->data['pager'] = $this->pager` with `$this->data['pager'] = $this->model->pager` It looks odd to call pager on the controller though I don't know the Relations library you're using. Give a look at what query `$this->model->orderBy('created_at, id', 'DESC')` gives you aswell. It might guide you if there's a problem in your SQL query.

Comment: thanks a lot @ViLar `$this->model->pager` solved the problem.